# CoreData migration of database to new codebase

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, core-data-migration

I am working on a large update to an app. By large update read complete reworking - completely new code base starting from scratch but with the same bundleID to be able to drop over the old app on release.

I am currently looking into the CoreData migration and am having some issues:

- The old app has a single database: `OldData`
- The new app will have multiple databases but only one which we are interested in: `NewData`

I want to load the information from `OldData`, migrate it manually into `NewData` and then delete the data in `OldData`.

We have copied a version of `OldData` into the new app but when we search for the saved objects nothing is returned.

We return the database:

```
let coreDataManager = CoreDataManager(modelName: "OldData")
let context = coreDataManager.persistentContainer.viewContext

if try context.count(for: NSFetchRequest(entityName: "OldObjectName")) > 0 {
```

the context exists but then doesn't return anything.

I have investigated mappingModels but this seems to require us to have access to the old data to be able to map it, currently there is no old data available in the new app.

There doesn't seem to be much information about migrating CoreData between codebases and rather focuses on updating the version of the database you are using.

What have I tried:

- I have verified that the CoreData is not being deleted by the new app being added over the top. When I reload the old app the data is still there
- When testing I am able to access the same UserDefaults between the two projects which again reassures me the data is there but not being accessed
- Investigating migration tutorials online - all of which seem to focus around migrating between versions or inside of the same code base

It feels like this should be easier than I am making it

1. Is this even possible? - do we have to use the `same` database - as in we can only do this in the original codebase as even a copy of the old database is different
2. Am I just doing something wrong on the configuration side - does the database link in to the project name or something else that is different between the two projects.

One of the issues that makes this slightly more tricky is that we don't have any scope to make modifications to the old code - we just have to write the new code to migrate the old.

**EDIT 1:**
In my investigations I noticed that the code generation of the two project databases are different - Objective-C in the old project and swift in the new. When I initially imported the `OldData` it was still Objective-C code generation. Once I switched it to swift the old database started appearing but the saved objects were still not appearing in my fetch.

I am not sure if this could be an issue caused by the difference in code generation for language

**EDIT 2:**
After doing some testing having different code generator languages does not appear to cause any issue.

I did however notice that the SQL databases are being stored in different places:

The old one is being stored in the `Documents` folder and the new one in the `Application Support` folder. There is some mention of the change in a relevant article [here](https://cocoacasts.com/where-to-store-a-core-data-persistent-store)

This means that the issue might be that we have the two SQL files in different places means that rather than using the old one the database is creating a new empty one.

I am going to continue focusing on how I can point the old database in my new app to a different location when configuring.

Answer (score 0):

So I eventually found the cause of the issue and a rough solution.

```
 private func migrateOldDatabase() {
     if let documentsPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .libraryDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
     // We need to migrate the three old sql files into the new store location
     let pathSuffixToMigrate = ["Metlink.sqlite", "Metlink.sqlite-shm", "Metlink.sqlite-wal"]

     let fileManager = FileManager.default

     for suffix in pathSuffixToMigrate {
         let path = documentsPath.appendingPathComponent(suffix)
         if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: path.path) {
            let applicationStorePath = documentsPath.appendingPathComponent("Application Support")

            do {
                let newCoredataMetlinkLocation = applicationStorePath.appendingPathComponent(suffix)
                // If there is already the same file we delete it to ensure we migrate the one we want
                if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: newCoredataMetlinkLocation.path) {
                    try fileManager.removeItem(at: newCoredataMetlinkLocation)
                }
                // We then copy the new one into its place
                try fileManager.copyItem(at: path, to: newCoredataMetlinkLocation)
            } catch {
                print("error")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We call it **BEFORE** we fetch the persistentContainer .

```
migrateOldDatabase()
let metlinkCoreDataManager = CoreDataManager(modelName: "Metlink")
let metlinkDBcontext = metlinkCoreDataManager.persistentContainer.viewContext
```

I will give a brief explanation for what is going on.

It seems that previously CoreData was stored in the Library folder. Now though it is stored in the Application Support folder in the library folder by default. This means when I tried to migrate the system would look for the old database, not find it and so create a new empty one in Application Support.

What we are doing here is checking whether we have one in the old location and copying all three sql files into the new location (whilst removing the old ones if there were any there). I found there were issues if we only copied across a single one.

We can see this represented here:

[image]

You can see my new databases which we are then manually migrating the data into.

I am fully aware that hard coding the locations is not an optimum solution and would not recommend it as a first method to try. In my case we are only attempting a migration on the first time the user loaded the new app meaning it would not be an on going danger.

It is worth noting that there is almost certainly a more correct solution than the one above. I found this very useful article [here](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/moving-core-data-files/) which is almost certainly the right way to do it if you want to change the location of your coredata database. I unfortunately couldn't get it working due to the different locations caused by the older version of coredata.